# Resolve itgenuty436 error during synchronization in Excel with database

Tags: invantive-control

When running synchronization on Invantive Control for one spreadsheet which downloads data from multiple databases, I get this error with error code itgenuty436:

> Kon het Excel bereik ''Exact transacties'!$A$2:$R$31617' niet
>   verwijderen en de overgebleven cellen verplaatsen/
>
> Controleer of uw recente wijzigingen in het model een Excel-tabel van
>   omvang proberen te veranderen of anderszins wijzigen. In dat geval
>   zorg ervoor dat de Excel-tabel juist gedefinieerd en gewijzigd wordt.
>   Indien nodig, verander de Excel-tabel in alleen cellen, synchroniseer
>   en maak de Excel-tabel opnieuw. Deze bewerking is niet toegestaan. U
>   probeert cellen in een tabel op het werkblad te verschuiven.

The same spreadsheet previously synchronized fine. What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be triggered by pushing "Remove downloaded facts" in the synchronize split button menu.

What happens is that the downloaded area (whose range can be seen in the block properties -> advanced) is removed through Excel actions and then reconstructed.

You can manually reproduce this by selecting the indicated range in Excel and selecting "Delete" and then "Shift cells up". This returns a rather vague error from Excel itself. Invantive Control has some extra text on it, but it remains vague.

What in my scenario happened was that due to continuous changes in the Excel model an Excel table was introduced at $A$1:$C$7815. Which is a subsection of the range occupied by the block data.

[image: In block contained Excel table]

The block itself with database data was just a named range, not an Excel table-based block.

Excel is not smart enough that when you delete a range with an embedded Excel table, that it removes the tables completely first.

Solution was to change the Excel table to a named range and then press "Remove downloaded facts" again from the sync menu.